# Show all listings by default on Flippa

Tags: flippa.com

Flippa.com defaults to showing only featured listings.  Each time I log in I have to click to show all of them.  Is there a way to set this to be the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as an option in your profile settings.

You'll have to resort to saving the filtered listings as a bookmark and hitting that again after you've logged back in.

Comment: Thanks.  That's exactly what I'm doing.  Appreciate the answer.